# Chat with custom data

Tags: chatbot

I am building a chatbot for a very small agency for their website . There is strict budget constraint.  I do not want to exiting LLM (via embeddings) as it might not be very cost efficient . Also , the knowledge base is small.
So, in a nutshell I want to build a language model like chatgpt for my custom data and deploy it as an API. Use the API in a chatbot . The chatbot will be in a html page.

Looking for suggestions or reference to any existing work might be useful